# If HTML is sent through $.get(..), jquery data table is not properly formatted

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

If in `content.php` I do not fill the table with the data, then I can see properly formatted jquery data table. However, if I fill it with the data (I tried both DB data and manual input of some random numbers), it is not formatted anymore and looks like a hell. Could it happen that `$.get(..)` (used in `test.php`) does not work properly in this example?

**test.php**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadContent();
    });

    function loadContent() {
                            $.get('modules/mod_scheduler/content.php', function(data) {
                                $('#table').html(data);
                            });     
    }

<div id="table"></div>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
    include_once '../../include/connect_db.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `TestTable`";
    $result=execute_query($query);

?>



    <table id="newspaper-b" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Flight Num</th>
                                <th scope="col">Appearance Time</th>
                                <th scope="col">Target Time</th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        $flightNum=$row['flightNum'];
                                        $appearanceTime=$row['appearanceTime'];
                                        $targetTime=$row['targetTime'];
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $flightNum; ?></td>
                                <td>

                                        <?php echo $appearanceTime;?>

                                </td>
                                <td>

                                        <?php echo $targetTime;?>

                                </td>

                                <td id="<?php echo $flightNum; ?>">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src='modules/images/edit.png' alt='Edit' />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Of course, I have also defined the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="modules/mod_scheduler/css/demo_table.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="modules/mod_scheduler/css/demo_page.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="modules/mod_scheduler/css/demo_table_jui.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/mod_scheduler/js/dataTable/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/mod_scheduler/js/dataTable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="modules/mod_scheduler/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean under "looks like a hell"? Have you tried to put it directly in test.php?

Comment: I see nothing really bad in your content.php. Except maybe id="<?php echo $flightNum; ?>" - but if $flightNum is just a number - should be no problem here. Can you please show a screen with good/bad appearance?

Comment: If you are not getting proper formatting on either Manual and fetched Data Then the probable reason would be Conflict in the CSS or JQuery.

Comment: @Dheeraj Joshi: Yes,maybe that's really the case. Let me check it.

Comment: @YouKuper - as I understand, you have good results when you `$.get` without running `while` loop in content.php. But have some problems when it is executed. If that is correct - than you have some styles for td/div that break your table appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a table, but you are not calling `dataTable()` on it that I can see. The way the DataTables plugin works, you typically call the `dataTable()` on a table. I can't recall what should happen with "arbitrary" style sheets (whatever styles you've set for the table), but certainly if you're using jQuery UI (which it looks like you are), it won't look right until you call the function, thereby adding all the necessary classes for jQuery UI theme. You could return those classes already in the table, but currently you are not.

Since you are doing this server-side, I would take it a step further and return JSON-formatted data for the table instead of a whole bunch of table markup. That's the more elegant and manageable way of using DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload stylesheets on ajax update, but it should auto apply CSS styles on new elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadContent();
});

function loadContent() {
    $.get('modules/mod_scheduler/content.php', function(data) {
        $('#table').html(data);
        var randomString = '?r=' + Math.random();
        $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function () {
            this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, randomString);
        }); 
    });
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try to apply the generated content from AJAX manually in that `table` div, maybe you have an error in you css .. some `//` as comments .. I make mistakes like that ..

Comment: Do you really beleave that this is the problem? How that can help at all?

Comment: It helps in refreshing css applied to html, @YouKuper I have modified and added the reload inside `$.get` .. try now

Comment: Well... I'm afraid there is something with document structure and not a browser bug (styles not applied to dynamically added content)

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: Unfortunately, the problem is the same. I tried running test.php separately and it worked fine.

Comment: then your problem is elsewhere ..maybe like @FAngel said .. with document structure ..

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: What exactly do you mean by 'document structure'? Is there any alternative approach to show data table in DIV #table without using $get(...)?

Comment: No, it a correct way, and I've tested and it applies CSS with and without my solution. I thought you needed to reload css. Try to add the generated HTML manually to see if the styles are applied without ajax